# How to create multi-line descriptions for TODOs in org-mode?

Tags: org-mode

I've got TODOs that I need to have a long description for but org-mode keeps telling me I have a `malformed drawer` and adds an additional `:PROPERTIES:` section. Here's an example of the problem.

```
*** My task title
    DEADLINE: <2018-01-30 Tue>
    :PROPERTIES:                             <-- adds this section
    :END:                                    <--
    :PROPERTIES:
    :DESCRIPTION: Questions to address:
What is the moon made of?
How many questions can you create for this sample?
What does Google do when you're not searching?
    :END:
```

Are multi-line descriptions simply not supported or am I formatting things improperly?

Comment: Can't you just use the paragraph belonging to the headline?

Comment: Perhaps, but then I cannot fold the task to see others more easily...

Comment: If there's some other property for storing notes, that would also work just fine. (BTW, thanks for helping me again :-)

Comment: I don't get the message `malformed drawer` with org-version 9.1.6. Why do you create two property drawers? One would be sufficient.

Comment: I just created one, but then it adds that first empty section after I specify "Yes" to the question of fixing the malformed drawer. That happens when I try to set a deadline (some other action) on a different TODO. Sorry I didn't clarify that earlier.

Comment: I've added a note about `org-show-children` in my answer that should make this question superfluous.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/72399/discussion-between-christian-di-lorenzo-and-tobias).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The org-mode manual says that property value pairs must be on the same line:

> Each property is specified on a single
>   line, with the key (surrounded by colons) first, and the value after it.

But you may extend a given property by `+:`.

> If you want to add to the value of an existing property, append a ‘+’
>   to the property name.  The following results in the property ‘var’
>   having the value “foo=1 bar=2”.
>
> ```
> #+PROPERTY: var  foo=1
> #+PROPERTY: var+ bar=2
> ```

So instead of

```org
*** My task title
    :PROPERTIES:
    :DESCRIPTION: Questions to address:
What is the moon made of?
How many questions can you create for this sample?
What does Google do when you're not searching?
    :END:
```

you would have to write

```org
*** My task title
    :PROPERTIES:
    :DESCRIPTION: Questions to address:
    :DESCRIPTION+: What is the moon made of?
    :DESCRIPTION+: How many questions can you create for this sample?
    :DESCRIPTION+: What does Google do when you're not searching?
    :END:
```

Calling `org-schedule` on the headline then gives you correctly:

```org
*** Another task title
    SCHEDULED: <2018-01-29 Mon 10:00>
    :PROPERTIES:
    :DESCRIPTION: Questions to address:
    :DESCRIPTION+: What is the moon made of?
    :DESCRIPTION+: How many questions can you create for this sample?
    :DESCRIPTION+: What does Google do when you're not searching?
    :END:
```

Even if the notation in the buffer gives the impression of a multi-line property the actual value of `DESCRIPTION` just contains one line. That may be important if you need that value for further processing.

---

Note, that you should use the paragraph below the section instead of the `DESCRIPTION` property if the description is that long. In the paragraph you have also better structural means such as lists.

You can limit the revealed tree view to headers with <kbd>C-u</kbd> `org-show-children` or with the corresponding outline key sequence <kbd>C-u C-TAB</kbd>.